# Please explain why we use 32768 in Audio Signals

Tags: python, audio-recording, voice-recognition, voice, noise-reduction

I'm new to audio signals.
What is the value 32768 that we use here?

Sample code:

```
rate, data = wavfile.read(wav_loc)
data = data / 32768
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that the wav-file is 16 bit integer, the range is [-32768, 32767], thus dividing by 32768 (2^15) will give the proper twos-complement range of [-1, 1]

Comment: `(32767 / 32768) < 1.0` though? So range is [-1.0, 1.0)?

Answer (score 1):

Another answer is that -32767 to +32767 is proper audio (to be symmetrical) and 32768 means that the audio clipped at that point